# How to extend global named functions in Typescript

Tags: typescript, extend

I've define a global named function such as:

```
function foo() { 
  foo._cache = {}; 
}
```

How do I extend a property to `foo` like `_cache`.

It seems the code below has no effact.

```
interface foo {
    _cache: any;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I extend a property to foo like _cache.

The function `foo` is not associated with the interface `foo` as they are in completely different declaration spaces ([more on those](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/declarationspaces.html)).

If you want `foo` to be a `function` that also has a `cache` property you have to do it in two steps e.g:

```
const foo: {
    (): void;
    _cache: any;
} = function () {
} as any;
foo._cache = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found the solution in offical documents: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Declaration%20Merging.md#merging-namespaces-with-classes